# Function that groups rows returned from SQL DB

Tags: javascript, node.js, lodash.js

I have a data set returned from an SQL database contained below, as you can see all data remains the same apart from one property, "name_alt".

```
[{
    "language_id": "tly",
    "language_name": "Talysh",
    "speakers_native": 800000,
    "total_speakers": 912000,
    "name_alt": "Taleshi",
    "country_main": "az"
}, {
    "language_id": "tly",
    "language_name": "Talysh",
    "speakers_native": 800000,
    "total_speakers": 912000,
    "name_alt": "Talish",
    "country_main": "az"
}, {
    "language_id": "tly",
    "language_name": "Talysh",
    "speakers_native": 800000,
    "total_speakers": 912000,
    "name_alt": "Talishi",
    "country_main": "az"
}, {
    "language_id": "tly",
    "language_name": "Talysh",
    "speakers_native": 800000,
    "total_speakers": 912000,
    "name_alt": "Talysh",
    "country_main": "az"
}, {
    "language_id": "tly",
    "language_name": "Talysh",
    "speakers_native": 800000,
    "total_speakers": 912000,
    "name_alt": "Talyshi",
    "country_main": "az"
}, {
    "language_id": "lez",
    "language_name": "Lezghian",
    "speakers_native": 171400,
    "total_speakers": 428400,
    "name_alt": "Kiurinsty",
    "country_main": "ru"
}, {
    "language_id": "lez",
    "language_name": "Lezghian",
    "speakers_native": 171400,
    "total_speakers": 428400,
    "name_alt": "Kiurinty",
    "country_main": "ru"
}, {
    "language_id": "lez",
    "language_name": "Lezghian",
    "speakers_native": 171400,
    "total_speakers": 428400,
    "name_alt": "Lezghi",
    "country_main": "ru"
}]
```

I want to combine all the name_alts into an array, so my data looks like the below:

```
[{
    "language_id": "tly",
    "language_name": "Talysh",
    "speakers_native": 800000,
    "total_speakers": 912000,
    "name_alt": ["Talesh", "Taleshi", "Talish", "Talishi", "Talyshi"],
    "country_main": "az"
}, {
    "language_id": "lez",
    "language_name": "Lezghian",
    "speakers_native": 171400,
    "total_speakers": 428400,
    "name_alt": ["Kiurinsty", "Kiurinty", "Lezghi", "Lezgi", "Lezgian", "Lezgin"],
    "country_main": "ru"
}]
```

I have written this function which takes the array, maps and filters it to return the data set I require. It works, but I am concerned it's not very performant. It takes the array that I want to compress (`array`), the property that I want to group by (`mappedProperty`), the property that should remain unique for every row (`uniqueProperty`) and a property that should be excluded from the set of grouped properties (`mainProperty`)

Could you review?

```
function reduceRows(array, mappedProperty, uniqueProperty, mainProperty) {
    var currentUniqueProp;
    var objToReturn;
    var mappedObj = _.map(array, function(obj) {
            // we're grouping by the unique property (i.e. an ID), so if we have a new
            // unique property, we clone the object, and start adding the
            // mapped property (i.e. alternative names for a language) to the array
            //usage: u.reduceRows(data.data.languages, "name_alt", "language_id", "language_name")
            if (obj[uniqueProperty] != currentUniqueProp) {
                objToReturn = _.clone(obj)
                objToReturn[mappedProperty] = [obj[mappedProperty]]
                currentUniqueProp = obj[uniqueProperty]
            } else {
                // sometimes the grouped property has a value which is the same as the main property
                // i.e. the language_name is also included in the list of name_alts
                // We want to avoid this duplication
                if (obj[mappedProperty] != obj[mainProperty]) {
                    objToReturn[mappedProperty].push(obj[mappedProperty])
                }
            }
            return objToReturn;
        })
    var filteredObj = _.filter(mappedObj, function(obj) {
        //this function ensures that only one entry for each unique property
        //is returned
        if (obj[uniqueProperty] == currentUniqueProp) {
            return false
        } else {
            currentUniqueProp = obj[uniqueProperty]
            return true
        }
    })
    return filteredObj
}
```

Comment: Don't know if javascript has `else if` but if yes you should use it at the first `if..else`.

Comment: JS has `else if`

Comment: `objToReturn` is a confusing name. It should describe what it represents and not what you plan on doing with it later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several things:

- You don't need underscore. Node supports ECMAScript 5 features such as `Array.prototype.map` and `Array.prototype.filter`.

  Replace `_.map(array, function)` with `array.map(function)`, etc.
- Name your inline functions. It's better for readability, and if the code errors out, you won't get `(anonymous function)` without knowing *which* anonymous function.
- `map` is used to *map one array into another array*, if you just want to iterate an array and run a function, you want `Array.prototype.forEach`.

I'd adopt a different method for doing this.

1. Figure out the unique entries (aside from name_alt)
2. Iterate over each "group" of unique entries, and `reduce` each to a single object
3. push each newly created object into a new array.

Here's my take:

```
// ## Get an array of language_ids to be used as a unique key. 
// ## I'm assuming here that if language_id is equal, the rest (aside from name_alt) is also equal.
var uniqueKeys = data
    .map(function pluckLanguageId(obj) { return obj.language_id; }) 
    //Now your array looks like ["a", "a", "a", "b", "b" ,"b"]
    .filter(function makeUnique(language, index, array) { return array.indexOf(language) === index; }); 
    //Now your array looks like ["a", "b"]

// ## Map each of the keys to a formatted object:
var result = uniqueKeys.map(function mapKeysToFormattedObjects(key) {
    //Take the entire data array
    return data
        //Filter it by language_id
        .filter(function getOnlyDataWithKey(item) { return item.language_id === key; }) 
        //Then combine it into one object
        .reduce(function combineToOneObject(previous, current) { 
            if (typeof(previous.name_alt) === "string") { //In this first object, the name_alt would be a string.
                previous.name_alt = [previous.name_alt]; //So make it into an array!
            }
            previous.name_alt.push(current.name_alt); //Push the current name_alt into the previous one.
            return previous;
        }); //Result is an object with all of the name_alts in an array
})
```

This is assuming that your original data is in that `data` variable. Please tell me if there's something you don't understand, and I'll try my best to explain.

Notice how I'm **chaining** my calls to map, filter and reduce. Both `map` and `filter` *return an array*, so the chained call is performed on that *newly processed array*.

A fancier way of writing this would be factoring everything out into functions, and then having a oneliner:

```
function pluckLanguageId(obj) { return obj.language_id; }
function makeUnique(language, index, array) { return array.indexOf(language) === index; }

function mapKeysToFormattedObjects(key) {
    return data
        .filter(function getOnlyDataWithKey(item) { return item.language_id === key; }) 
        .reduce(function combineToOneObject(previous, current) { 
            if (typeof(previous.name_alt) === "string") { //In this first object, the name_alt would be a string.
                previous.name_alt = [previous.name_alt]; //So make it into an array!
            }
            previous.name_alt.push(current.name_alt); //Push the current name_alt into the previous one.
            return previous;
        }); //Result is an object with all of the name_alts in an array
}

var result = data.map(pluckLanguageId).filter(makeUnique).map(mapKeysToFormattedObjects);
//One liner!
```

This code can be improved even further with functions that return functions and whatnot, but take the first example as reference to learn from.

Answer (score 2):

As `javascript` has a `else if` statement you should use this to remove one level of indention.

```
if (obj[uniqueProperty] != currentUniqueProp) {
    objToReturn = _.clone(obj)
    objToReturn[mappedProperty] = [obj[mappedProperty]]
    currentUniqueProp = obj[uniqueProperty]
} else if (obj[mappedProperty] != obj[mainProperty]) {
    // sometimes the grouped property has a value which is the same as the main property
    // i.e. the language_name is also included in the list of name_alts
    // We want to avoid this duplication

    objToReturn[mappedProperty].push(obj[mappedProperty])
}
```

The `underscore` filter method can be simplified to

```
var filteredObj = _.filter(mappedObj, function(obj) {
    //this function ensures that only one entry for each unique property
    //is returned
    if (obj[uniqueProperty] == currentUniqueProp) {
        return false
    }
    currentUniqueProp = obj[uniqueProperty]
    return true
})
```

If the condition evaluates to `true` the method returns, so no `else` is needed.

You should always declare your variables where they are needed. So `var objToReturn` should be declared here

```
var mappedObj = _.map(array, function(obj) {
        var objToReturn;
        // we're grouping by the unique property
```